# PHP & HTML with PayPal integration code won't work

Tags: php, html, paypal

I'm trying to create a system now using PHP that will work out the cost of a product that a user is purchasing. Basically I wan't to have lots of radio buttons and depending on what one the user selects the price changes.

In the code below you will be able to see my PHP. And obviously my HTML this will probably give a better idea of what I am trying to achieve. It's my first time coding in PHP I usually use JavaScript so I expect there may be a few errors please help me!.

At the end of this basically I need a webpage that submits a custom amount to the PayPal button dependent on what options for the product the user has chosen (8gb of ram not 4gb and 500gb drive not 1tb etc).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Silicon Build</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css">
        <script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
        <!-- Custom CSS Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="scss/app.css">
        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <?php
            function updateTotal($type, $price) {
                $cpu = 50;
                $ram = 100;
                $mobo = 150;
                $components = $cpu + $ram + $mobo;
                $shippingMe = 6.90;
                $profit = 35;
                $shipping = 15;
                $original = (300 + $shippingMe + $shipping + $profit + 0.2) /0.966;
                $basePrice = ($components + $shippingMe + $shipping + $profit + 0.2) /0.966;
                $options = $basePrice - $original;
                if ($type == 'cpu') {
                    $cpu = $price;
                } else if ($type == 'ram') {
                    $ram = $price;
                } else if ($type == 'mobo') {
                    $mobo = $price;}
            }
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Navigational Menu -->
        <?php include_once("header.html"); ?>
        <!-- Main Content -->
        <input type="radio" name="cpu" value="Intel-i5" oncheck="<?php updateTotal('cpu',50); ?>" checked>Intel Core i5 (+£0.00)<br>
        <input type="radio" name="cpu" value="Intel-i7" onclick="<?php updateTotal('cpu',70); ?>">Intel Core i7 (+£20.00)<br>
        <hr>
        <input type="radio" name="ram" value="4gb" onclick="<?php updateTotal('ram',100); ?>" checked>4GB RAM (+£0.00)<br>
        <input type="radio" name="ram" value="8gb" onclick="<?php updateTotal('ram',150); ?>">8GB RAM (+£50.00)<br>
        <hr>
        <input type="radio" name="mobo" value="mobo1" onclick="<?php updateTotal('mobo',150); ?>" checked>Motherboard 1 (+£0.00)<br>
        <input type="radio" name="mobo" value="mobo2" onclick="<?php updateTotal('mobo',175); ?>">Motherboard 2 (+£25.00)<br>
        
        <p id="price"></p>
        <p id="options"></p>
        
        <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="nick@bayworth.com">
            <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="BM">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="COMPUTER_NAME">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $basePrice; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
            <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
            <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.00">
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
            <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
        </form>

        
        <!-- Footer -->
        <?php include_once("footer.html"); ?>
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

onclick="" this doesn't work, onclick can only execute javascript. No need to use PHP here I think, javascript will can do the function you expect.